# LSTM higher validation accuracy at higher validation loss ( Python: Keras )

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, loss

When training my LSTM ( using the Keras library in Python ) the validation loss keeps increasing, although it eventually does obtain a higher validation accuracy. Which leads me to 2 questions:

1. How/Why does it obtain a (significantly) higher validation accuracy at a (significantly) higher validation loss?
2. Is it problematic that the validation loss increases? ( because it eventually does obtain a good validation accuracy either way )

This is an example history log of my LSTM for which this applies:

[image]

As visible when comparing epoch 0 with epoch ~430:

52% val accuracy at 1.1 val loss vs. 61% val accuracy at 1.8 val loss

For the loss function I'm using tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy and I'm using the SGD optimizer at a high learning rate of 50-60% ( as it obtained the best validation accuracy with it ).

Initially I thought it may be overfitting, but then I don't understand how the validation accuracy does eventually get quite a lot higher at almost 2 times as high of a validation loss.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Another example of a different run, less fluctuating validation accuracy but still significantly higher validation accuracy as the validation loss increases:

[image]

In this run I used a low instead of high dropout.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, **"at a high learning rate of 50-60%"**, this might be the reason why graphs are oscillating. Lowering the learning rate or adding regularization should solve the oscillating problem.

More generally,

Cross Entropy loss is **not a bounded loss**, so having very badly outliers would make it explode.

- Accuracy can go higher which means your model is able to learn the rest of the dataset except the outliers.
- Validation set has too many outliers that causing the oscillation of the loss values.

To conclude if you are overfitting or not, you should inspect validation set for outliers.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I'll look into the outliers in the validation set first. I suppose it may indeed be doing a lot worse on the outliers ( but resulting in the same prediction/classification ) while improving acc on the rest of the data for which it was close to predicting correct. As for the high learning rate, lowering it results in a significantly lower validation accuracy. Setting the learning rate to 50-60% seemed to be the sweet spot for the best validation accuracy for my model. Btw I do have dropout layers for regularlization, but even with high dropout values the "issue" remains.

Comment: P.S. do you have any tips on how I can identify outliers? E.g. just determine the samples for which the predicted probability of the correct class is the lowest? ( so for which the loss is the highest )

Comment: For your case, it seems learning rate is the problem. You are overshooting minimum point that yielding up and down fluctation. You need to lower it or use another optimizer, or if you insist on using SGD you need to tweak your LR by epochs. By tweaking LR you can get better results without overshooting. You can try L2 regularization as well. Regarding to your second question, you can use cluster based anomaly detection ( I assume you are working on time series)

Comment: I'll look into the cluster based anomally detection! As for the LR, is there any way to measure whether my LR is (still) too high? E.g. you mentioned because it's fluctuating much, but is there any concrete limit to how much the validation accuracy should fluctuate in order to optimize results? ( or a different formal method to determine whether my LR is too high )
EDIT: I added another example run, where the validation accuracy isn't fluctuating as much but it still increases at a higher validation loss.

Comment: It is hard to tell without the details of the dataset, but you can use ReduceLROnPlateu callback, LR scheduler. If LR tweaking would not help I would change the optimizer and see the difference.

Comment: Understandable, I'll try playing with the optimizer and its parameters to see if I can get more consistent results. Thanks for the help!